# About Open MP and cudaSetDevice()

Tags: c++, c, cuda, openmp, nvidia

Does anyone know if the following usage of `cudaSetDevice` is correct? I want to repeatedly call resources created on different devices at any time, in any host thread; is there a way to do this in CUDA?

```
 cudaSetDevice(0);
 /...create cuda streams and do some memory allocation on gpu.../
 cudaSetDevice(1);
 /...create cuda streams and do some memory allocation on gpu.../
 #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
 { 
   int omp_threadID=omp_get_thread_num();
    ....
   if (omp_threadID==0)
   {
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    /...calling streams/memory created on device 0.../
   }
   else
   {
    cudaSetDevice(1);
    /...calling streams/memory created on device 1.../
    }; 
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like that should work.  Make sure that all things you created on device 0, you only use in OpenMP thread 0, and likewise for device 1 and thread 1.

You may also want to look at the [CUDA OpenMP Sample Code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cudaopenmp), which demonstrates how to use OpenMP threads to each manage an individual device.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why I have to use these in a single OMP thread? I think if I can ensure syncs between OMP threads such that not more than one thread calling one device (and do somethings there) at a time, I can use cudaSetDevice() from any threads calling any stuff at any proper time freely?

Comment: I was pointing out that in your example, you have the OMP thread 0 code starting out with `cudaSetDevice(0);` and so you should only be working with device 0 at that point.  Likewise in thread 1, you start with `cudaSetDevice(1);` and so at that point you should only be working with device 1.  And this is consistent with how the sample code I referenced works.